# How can I set a blank line as a boundary to repeat a function?

Tags: php, html

I have a text area in my html form.I am collecting the data from this form using POST method.Here I need to set a blank line as a boundary to repeat a function using this form data.
for example I am calculating the sum of the digits which are collected from this text area using below code

```
<?php
$devices = $_POST['devs'];
$count = array_sum(explode("\n", $devices));
echo "sum is $count";
?>
```

If I enter below digits

```
1
2
3
```

I will get output like:

```
sum is 6
```

and what I need is, if I put digits like

```
1
2
3

4
5
6
```

I need output like

```
sum is 6
sum is 15
```

how can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there isn't any extra whitespace in your data, this can be accomplished very similarly to your current approach, by adding an extra step to explode on *two* newlines, and then calling your current code on each part:

```
$devices = $_POST['devs'];
$repeats = explode(PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL, $devices); // Favor PHP_EOL (end of line) to avoid cross OS issues
foreach($repeats as $repeat)
{
  $count = array_sum(explode(PHP_EOL, $repeat));
  echo "sum is $count".PHP_EOL;
}
```

Obviously, if there is extra whitespace, then you'll need to do a cleanup step first.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. this sum operation is an example. If I need to do multiple operations and echo using this data, what will be the best approach ?

Comment: If you simply need to do one complex operation (that takes multiple operations to complete) over multiple sets of data, then you just put the whole operation inside the foreach block - it will be repeated once per element of the $repeats array. If you need to do different operations for different elements of $repeats, then it will depend on the real nature of the data in the form.

Comment: @ SterlingDragon  : Thank you. can you have a look into this fiddle.this is the actual code I need to repeat.  http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/nug-pkh

Comment: Clearly, there's more context than what is in the fiddle, but your approach is standard and does do what you're asking for. :)